# What is $m\angle CEF?$

Tags: geometry

In the figure $ABCD$ is a kite with $|AB|=|BC|, |DE|=|EF|, m\angle A=80^\circ,$ and $m\angle B=120^\circ.$ What is $m\angle CEF?$
[image]

My attemp is: $m\angle D=m\angle DFE$

$m\angle D+m\angle DFE+180^\circ-?=180^\circ\Rightarrow$

$2m\angle D=m\angle DFE=?\Rightarrow m\angle D=m\angle DFE=\frac{?}{2}$

$80^\circ+120^\circ+m\angle C+m\angle ?+180^\circ-\frac{?}{2}=540^\circ$

$2m\angle C+?=180^\circ$

I didn't now how to continue. Help me please. Thank you very much.

Comment: (Edit with a little correction; thanks to @MattG88) The sum of angles of a quadrilateral being 360°, and angle $\angle BCE=80°$ , angle  $\angle EDF$=360°-80-80-120°=80°, thus angle $\angle DEF$ =180°-80°-80°=20°, and the solution is 180°-20°=160°.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Kite then we know that $|AD|=|DC|$.

Then we can give the following proof:
$$
\triangle ABD \cong\triangle CBD
$$$$
m\angle C = m\angle A = 80^\circ
$$$$
m\angle A +m\angle B + m\angle C + m\angle D = 360^\circ
\\
80^\circ+120^\circ+80^\circ+m\angle D = 360^\circ
\\
m\angle D = 80^\circ
$$$$
m\angle DFE = m\angle D = 80^\circ
$$$$
m\angle D + m\angle DFE + m\angle DEF = 180^\circ
\\
80^\circ+80^\circ+m\angle DEF = 180^\circ
\\
m\angle DEF = 20^\circ
$$$$
?=180^\circ-m\angle DEF=180^\circ-20^\circ=160^\circ
$$
Thus we know that $?=160^\circ$.